# Help with powering LEDs in parallel with maximum brightness

Tags: arduino, led, current, resistance, parallel

I'm pretty new to engineering stuff and I'm scared that I may burn out my LEDs if left to my own devices (literally.) I'm trying to power 16-18 LEDs in parallel at maximum brightness. I have a surplus of 470 ohm resistors that I'd like to use if possible.

[Here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/YSL-R531R3C-A13.pdf) is the data sheet

Bonus question: What would it take to make them fade at adjustable levels via Arduino? I'm trying to make a red heart beating effect and blinking is kinda boring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase brightness of parallel LEDs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248307/increase-brightness-of-parallel-leds)

Comment: A manufacturer buys thousands of LEDs and tests them all, matching them into groups with the same forward voltage. Then they can connect a group of them in parallel. Will you buy thousands and match them into groups?? If you don't then the parallel LED with the lowest voltage will hog all the current and quickly burn out. then  the next LED will burn out then the next and on and on. You can make series strings of LEDs, each string having its own current-limiting resistor. Without matching all the LEDs then some strings will be brighter than other strings.

Comment: @audio op is already doing that, hence "surplus of 470 ohm resistors to use". And saying you need thousands is FUD anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for a resistor for an led is:

(Source Voltage - Led Target Forward Voltage) / Target Forward Current In Amps = Resistance

Assuming 5V since you are using an Arduino, 20 mA forward current so ~2.2V forward voltage, that is (5 - 2.2) / 0.02A = 140 Ohms. So much bigger than your 470 ohm resistors.

You have two options. You can put multiple resistors in parallel (3 470Ω resistors in parallel is 153 ohms so roughly 18 mA, not even discernible to the human eye in brightness difference), or you can increase the source voltage ((12V - 2.2) / 0.02 = 490 Ohms, close enough). Or you know, just get different resistors.

As for your question on fading the leds (as a whole), there is plenty of examples online for Arduino led PWM. Connect all your parallel leds+resistors to a transistor or mosfet and use the Arduino gpio to PWM the transistor base/mosfet gate. Or get even fancier. Google Arduino led marque or led chaser for examples on how to make the leds chase each other around the heart.